# How to use different functions out put in function?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a procedure which gives many values and I need to return maximum and minimum of these values to separate cells.

my procedure follows defining two different function for max and min, executing the same procedure!!

Is there a better way to do this?

```
Function Pmax(P, Mx, My, b, d, b1, d1, ex, ey)
P1 = (---------)
P2 = (---------)
P3 = (---------)
P4 = (---------)
Pmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(P1, P2, P3, P4)
End Function
Function Pmin(P, Mx, My, b, d, b1, d1, ex, ey)
P1 = (--------)
P2 = (--------)
P3 = (--------)
P4 = (--------)
Pmin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(P1, P2, P3, P4)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could define a Pn function that returns an array of P's values

```
Function Pn(P, Mx, My, b, d, b1, d1, ex, ey)
    P1 = '(---------)
    P2 = '(---------)
    P3 = '(---------)
    P4 = '(---------)

    Pn = Array(P1, P2, P3, P4)
End Function
```

and then use it in your `Pmin()` and `Pmax()` functions

```
Function Pmax(P, Mx, My, b, d, b1, d1, ex, ey)
    Pmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Pn(P, Mx, My, b, d, b1, d1, ex, ey))
End Function

Function Pmin(P, Mx, My, b, d, b1, d1, ex, ey)
    Pmin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Pn(P, Mx, My, b, d, b1, d1, ex, ey))
End Function
```

Comment: hahaha that was my answer too. Before I edited it. :D (except I used byref)

Comment: @Pierre, well your first answer was not quite this

Comment: that's because I modified it. ;-)

Comment: @Pierre, I'm referring to your _actual_ first edit, that still can be seen if you click the `edited ... ago` tag below your code. There you had a `Sub sousfonction()` not returning anything but accepting `ByRef` and setting parameters P1...P4. So that you had both to call first `sousfonction` and then `Pmin()`. While my solution uses a `Function` directly.  Anyhow it seems like devi didn't bother neither answers at all...

Comment: indeed your version is simpler&better in this matter :-)  I meant no offense, I was just having a small laugh as we had the same interpretation of the question. But indeed OP seems not to bother answering which is rude.

Comment: @Pierre, I got no offense and I was not saying my solution is better than yours, just pointing out it was different. As for rudeness, many people with  1 rep are likely to act as devi is doing by now

Comment: Yours is better, no debate, but still similar. :-)  Yes I had that several times, it is really annoying... such lack of etiquette is a shame.

Comment: I had to say it, you know it. :-)

Comment: Thank you Pierre  and user3598756. sorry for late acknowledgement as I am not regular here. I am using excel to develop my engineering calculation sheet so was not of urgent and it is learning. thank you again

Comment: I have this following question, In my engineering calculation I need to use some parameter again and again say for example all those parameters P,Mx,My,b,d,b1,d1,ex,ey.

Comment: I have this following question, In my engineering calculation I need to use some parameter again and again say for example all those parameters P,Mx,My,b,d,b1,d1,ex,ey. Now how I can define these parameters globally so that in functions it is not necessary to call or assign these parameters again and again?? Thank you in advance

Comment: devi, if you need to use them in different sub of the same `module` than place their declaration statement (e.g.:`Dim P As Double, Mx As Double,...`) at the top of it. If you need them to be shared among different `modules` you can define them as `Public` (e.g. `Public P As Double, Mx As Double, ...`) placing this declaration at the top of any of them... But don't say anybody I told you that.... BTW when addressing your comment to some user you have to suffix his/her name with "@" (e.g. "@user3598756")

Comment: @user3598756 thanks for the education really appreciated it. I run a test as follows but it not work

Comment: @user3598756  first I declared them as you said then wrote a function say function pn(P,Mx,My) -------- end function and now I have another function q which uses same parameter for another procedure  I tried as function q( ) ---- end function (with out putting parameters inside parenthesis) . it didn't work . Thank you

Comment: Wait. My info was about sharing variables between subs/functions of a VBA project. If you are using those function as UDF to be inpit in excel worksheet cells, then you have to use full _signature_

Answer (score 2):

```
Function Pminmax(P, Mx, My, b, d, b1, d1, ex, ey)
    P1 = (---------)
    P2 = (---------)
    P3 = (---------)
    P4 = (---------)
    dim a(1 to 2,1 to 1)
    a(1,1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(P1, P2, P3, P4)
    a(2,1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(P1, P2, P3, P4)
    Pminmax=a
End Function
```

in excel: select 2 cells, formula, ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: Good answer, can you just explain how to use in excel too ;)

Comment: done both :-) (was gonna add the part to use it on excel anyway :D )

Comment: Thank you Pierre ,user3598756 Both worked. Pierre I was off so could not see the answers. Thanks again.

Comment: @pierre thank you this helped me for a long time question.